# httpd loading 'Test Page' after adding httpd to startup

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, httpd, startup

I recently added `httpd` to start during the start up by doing this:

```
cd /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/
ln -s  /etc/init.d/httpd S80httpd
```

Although `httpd` starts on boot, seems like my `DocumentRoot` that was set in `httpd.conf` located in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` does not take effect and `Fedora Test Page` gets loaded.

When I used to start *httpd* manually by `httpd -k start`, everything was working fine.

I perhaps have not correctly understood the `<number>` part of `s<number>script` / `k<number>script` naming convention for the RC scripts.

Although, I know that it's for representing the order in which the script will be executed during the run of runlevel control script.

I picked up `S80httpd` from [How to auto start Apache during boot time](http://www.techiecorner.com/104/how-to-auto-start-apache-during-boot-time-linux/).

What is exactly happening?

I am using `Fedora 15` and `Apache/2.2.21`.

Comment: Assuming that you aren't accidentally running two different installs, I would poke around the `/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S80httpd` script to see if it mentions other config files then the ones you intend for it to use. Why are you linking that start up script? Did the package not install one for you?

Comment: @Tim no the package hadn't installed one. Looking into `S80httpd` script now.

Comment: @Tim the script says his `config: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. I definitely am not running two different installs.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, guess I will step back because I haven't used fedora in a few months, something may be wildly different then I remember.

Comment: Is `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` the correct config file where you have defined your doc root? Can you also post the entire stanza that has your docroot definition?

Comment: @Tim just a minute. And yes its is the correct config file.

Comment: @Tim `DocumentRoot "/ThinkingMonkey/mysite/site"`   
`DocumentRoot "/ThinkingMonkey/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html"`
both of the DocumentRoots have their virtualHost columns definied.

Comment: Is there an `Include` line in httpd.conf anywhere?

Comment: @Tim Cannot find an `Include` line. But the same configuration was working with manual start.

Comment: SELinux is set to enforcing

Answer (score 1):

Centos has a /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf which will load the generic welcome page. Check to see if that file exists on your fedora system. If so, move it out of the way, stop whichever instance of apache you have, and start apache via service httpd start, or /etc/init.d/apache start, etc.

Comment: There is a `welcome.conf`. But, since it starts properly when doing a manual start, It should also work with auto-start. The point is to start httpd during start not manually. as you can see by my question. Peace.

Comment: The manual start may not be reading your apache config the same way. See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Server_Test_Page I'm assuming you are seeing the testpage they show at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Server_Test_Page#Test_Page_Screenshot Are you seeing a different test page?

Comment: Yup, I am seeing the server page show at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/File:ServerTestPage_httpd_test_page.png.

Comment: So it is the /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf file. You can follow my directions, or Fedora's @ http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Server_Test_Page#How_can_I_make_this_page_go_away.3F which is to place an index.html file in the Docroot, or to comment out the file.

Comment: there is an index.php at the `DocumentRoot`. Will move the `welcome.conf` to another directory as my httpd.conf has `Include conf.d/*.conf`

Comment: If that works as you want, please accept the answer.

Comment: Did that, still does not work. Now I get `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
`
 I will up-vote for now.

Comment: Can you update the question with your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file? Did you yum install php?

Comment: Yes I did a yum install. Have added the info. Need any more info?

Comment: What is the result of running getenforce?

Comment: SELinux is set to enforcing

Comment: Dirty fix, disable SELinux via setenforce 0, and modifying /etc/sysconfig/selinux to set SELINUX=disabled. Or move the site into /var/www/html, and make sure the files have the proper selinux info for each file. Or look at how to set this info for the current doc roots.